# get SignalStrength without Using PhoneStateListener onSignalStrengthchanged

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, signal-strength

does anyone know how to get the signal strength without having to call the onSignalStrengthChanged.  The problem with onSignalStrengthchanged is that is it called when the signal strength changes and I need to get the value of signalstrength according to a different criteria.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

On API level 17 **only**, here's some code that can be used in an `Activity` (or any other `Context` child class):

```
import android.telephony.CellInfo;
import android.telephony.CellInfoCdma;
import android.telephony.CellInfoGsm;
import android.telephony.CellInfoLte;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthCdma;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthGsm;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthLte;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

try {
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    for (final CellInfo info : tm.getAllCellInfo()) {
        if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
            final CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
            // do what you need
        } else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
            final CellSignalStrengthCdma cdma = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
            // do what you need
        } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
            final CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
            // do what you need
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unknown type of cell signal!");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain cell signal information", e);
}
```

Previous versions of Android require you to call the listener, there is no other alternative (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674216/android-3g-signal-strength)).

Also ensure that your application contains the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can access SignalStrength via reflection call. Please go through the link for implementation http://blog.ajhodges.com/2013/03/reading-lte-signal-strength-rssi-in.html

Comment: I only get 99 for signal strength and -1 for Bit error rate. It doesnt seem to give me the real value. do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: As per the GSM Signal Strength, valid values are (0-31, 99) as defined in TS 27.007 8.5 `0        -113 dBm or less  
1        -111 dBm  
2...30   -109... -53 dBm  
31        -51 dBm or greater  

99 not known or not detectable` see more over [3GPP TS 27.007](http://m10.home.xs4all.nl/mac/downloads/3GPP-27007-630.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is another API in Android called CellInfo. But I am not sure whether signal strength returned by OnSignalStrengthsChanged() and CellInfo is same or not.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andre's answer above, in Kotlin you can use this one-liner (again API 17+):

```
fun getRadioSignalLevel(): Int {
  return when (val info = telephonyManager.allCellInfo?.firstOrNull()) {
    is CellInfoLte   -> info.cellSignalStrength.level
    is CellInfoGsm   -> info.cellSignalStrength.level
    is CellInfoCdma  -> info.cellSignalStrength.level
    is CellInfoWcdma -> info.cellSignalStrength.level
    else             -> 0
  }
}
```