# TelephonyManager: Callback function for SIM Operator Name change

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager

I'm developing an APP for mobile network testing.
The Home page of the APP shows the mobile network the SIM is registered to.
I need to keep this info updated, how can I do?

This is the current working code:

```
package com.giorgio.roamingqosapp.ui.home

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.giorgio.roamingqosapp.R
import com.giorgio.roamingqosapp.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        var text = ""

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }

        val tm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Activity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        val SIMOperatorName = tm.simOperatorName
        val isRoaming = tm.isNetworkRoaming

        if (SIMOperatorName != null) {
            text = getString(R.string.registered_operator, SIMOperatorName)
            binding.registeredOperator.text = text
        }
        text = when (isRoaming) {
            true -> getString(R.string.roaming, "Roaming")
            false -> getString(R.string.roaming, "Home")
        }
        binding.roaming.text = text

        val imageView: ImageView = binding.registeredImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.led_verde))
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

My goal is to keep binding.registeredOperator.text updated if the name of the operator changes

Comment: I've found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949063/action-phone-state-changed-not-called-on-network-cell-changes